# Different return types of a class method

Tags: apex

I am new to language Apex and learning basic stuff. I have follwing code (written for a trailhead challenge) and wondering about the success.

```
public static Account insertNewAccount(String AccountName) {
    Account acc = new Account(name = AccountName);

    try {
        insert acc;    
    }
    catch (DmlException e) {
        acc = null;
    }

    return acc;
}
```

The definition of the method says it will return an sObject Account - why is it possible to return a null instead? Are there better ways to declare that method will return Account OR Null?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Null` can be any type.
So returning a `Null` `Account` is perfectly valid.

You never need to declare that an `Account` will return an `Account` OR `Null` (and this is not possible) because every complex and primative data type can be `Null`.

See here for more information about primitive data types: [Primitive Data Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm) and here: [Data Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_data_types.htm)

More about `Null` here:

> If you declare a variable and don't initialize it with a value, it will be null. In essence, null means the absence of a value.
>
> You can also assign null to any variable declared with a primitive type.

Reference here: [Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm)

Comment: Yes I agree, If your function usually returns something but doesn't for some reason, `return null;` is the way to go. And it is always is a good practice to show what you're returning.

Comment: @RohitMourya I disagree when it comes to collections. Never return a null collection when you can avoid it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, makes sense.

Comment: A variable of any type can be null (not just complex ones), which leads to some weird things like `boolean`s that are neither true nor false.

Comment: I'm with you @AdrianLarson - never return a null collection - fixed the omission in the answer too (I was unsure about integers for some reason and had a quick check, but then forgot to update the answer)